# Custom field formatter fails in create()

Tags: datetime, plugins

PHPStorm, PHP 7.4
IDE highlights  $container->get('date.formatter'), with

> "Expected parameter of type '\Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface', 'object' provided"

This function is an exact copy of the core TimestampFormatter (which also shows the error)

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
  return new static(
    $plugin_id,
    $plugin_definition,
    $configuration['field_definition'],
    $configuration['settings'],
    $configuration['label'],
    $configuration['view_mode'],
    $configuration['third_party_settings'],
    $container->get('date.formatter'),
    $container->get('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('date_format')
  );
}
```

The __construct is looking for a DateFormatterInterface (see below) and not sure how this works in core, but my "viewElements" is never firing since this error started.

```
public function __construct($plugin_id, $plugin_definition, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, array $settings, $label, $view_mode, array $third_party_settings, **DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter**, EntityStorageInterface $date_format_storage) {
```

What is the proper container->get to use to return a proper date.formatter and not an object which causes the create to fail without any errors logged that I can see?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is fine, but you can remove the warnings by installing the [PHPStorm Symfony plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symfony-support.html#symfony-code-style).

It teaches the IDE how to resolve the correct class from the service name you provide to `$container->get()`.

Comment: Thanks @Clive as I've seen you answer thousands of questions over many years. Kudos. Strange thing is I have my field set to format based on this plugin but it is not called anymore when the node is viewed. It was working some time ago but not now. I have breakpoints set in the constructor and the viewElements but they never fire.

Comment: Adjusted IDE and warning did go away. I guess I misunderstand how the formatter works for a field when editing a node. My dateTime field format must change based on a condition. Does the formatter not interact with the widget that displays the date? Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Don't forget to the 'Symfony' plugin :-).